# jQuery for adding-delete button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, forms, uidatepicker

For one of my clients, I have developed an inquiry form as per the need. The data to be entered may be of multiples for which I designed the dynamic form so that the rows may be increased or decreased. The add button in the form  is working fine but the delete button is not working.

Please check the  [DEMO](http://www.piperate.com/contact.html) and code is given below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" class="i"  name="sl[]"><input type="text" class="l"  name="item[]"><input  type="text" class="j"  name="unit[]"><input type="text" class="j"  name="qty[]"/>&nbsp;<a href="#" class="remove_field">X</a></div>');

      //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
    
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy'
  });
});
```

```css
.k input {
  width: 95px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.i {
  width: 40px;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.l {
  width: 390px;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: left;
}
.j {
  width: 95px;
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.m {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<form method="post" action="xxx/enq.php">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="com" />
  <label>Required at:</label>
  <input type="text" name="req2" />
  <label>Location:</label>
  <input type="text" name="place" />
  <label>Required Dt:</label>
  <input type="text" name="req1" class="datepicker" />

  <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="i">SL</td>
        <td class="l">ITEM DESCRIPTION</td>
        <td class="j">UNIT</td>
        <td class="j">QTY</td</tr>
    </table>
    <input type="text" class="i" name="sl[]">
    <input type="text" class="l" name="item[]">
    <input type="text" class="j" name="unit[]">
    <input type="text" class="j" name="qty[]">
    <button class="add_field_button">+</button>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name='submit' onclick="show_confirm()" value="SUBMIT">
  <input type="reset" value="CLEAR">
</form>
```

I have tried in number of ways and googled but in vain.

Comment: Where's the delete button? You mean clear? (Oh nm I see, you mean to the right of the fields after you've added one first).

Comment: Please define "_is not working_".

Comment: When ever the "+" button is entered, it is adding a row with "X" button - that is delete button. Please check the demo by adding rows / deleting the rows, you may find the problem

Comment: Your code throws a console error (it's really useful to report this kind of thing) "$(...).on is not a function". It looks like someting is wrong with your input fields selection/wrapper.

Comment: Now I've put your code in a snippet, you can easily see the error. You've included jQuery twice. Remove one of them, preferably 1.6.2 as it's very out of date, and your code works fine. In future be sure to check the console *first* when debugging any JS issues.

Comment: Sir, I have checked the form. Whenever, I remove the date picker, both add / delete row is working.  But with date picker, only adding the row is working but not the delete.

Comment: Indeed, the delete button doens't work, it seems to paralyze your keyboard? "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. __Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful__ to other readers._" "Doesn't work" is not a problem description, please describe what you want your code to do, and what it does instead. Just a normal communication!

Answer (score 0):

Change the js of 'remove' functionality of the populated field

```
$(body).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
e.preventDefault();
$(this).parent('div').remove();
x--;
})
```

Comment: Sir, it is not wroking

Comment: try by removing e.preventdefault();

Comment: But your code is working Fine in the JsFiddle. here it is:https://jsfiddle.net/4tnzffa7/